# How to make a new table that looks similar to the original table

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, dax, tabular

I have an a table in PowerBI in which it has 3 columns.

- Id (referring to a cake ticket)
- Open Date
- Closed Date

All rows in the `Id` column are filled, as well in the `Open Date` Column which have a closed date. However, some rows in the `Closed Date` column are blank. Which means that ticket is still open and has not been finished.

I would like to make two new tables from the original table.

One table should have all the entries with blank `Closed Date`.

The second table should have all the entries with a filled `Closed Date`.

I attempted using the modeling tab in PowerBI and using the New Table button, but was unsuccessful in doing what I wanted.

Any tips, suggestions or anything will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `New Table` to achieve what you want.

[image: New Table]

Sample data:

```
Tickets = 
DATATABLE(
    "Id", INTEGER,
    "Open Date", DATETIME,
    "Closed Date", DATETIME,
    {
        {1, "2018-07-01", "2018-07-03"},
        {2, "2018-07-02", BLANK()},
        {3, "2018-07-03", "2018-07-10"},
        {4, "2018-07-04", BLANK()},
        {5, "2018-07-05", BLANK()}
    }
)
```

[image: Tickets]

Open tickets:

```
Open tickets = FILTER(Tickets, ISBLANK(Tickets[Closed Date]))
```

[image: Open tickets]

Closed tickets:

```
Closed tickets = FILTER(Tickets, Tickets[Closed Date])
```

[image: Closed tickets]

Note that `Tickets[Closed Date]` is the same as `NOT(ISBLANK(Tickets[Closed Date]))`.

Comment: Hi @cool-beans Does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.